# systemd invalid argument - debugging delayed hibernation service file

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

I'm trying to implement the [delayed hibernation unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Delayed_hibernation_service_file). I'm on arch/antergos.

```
>>> systemctl enable suspend-to-hibernate.service
Failed to enable unit ...to-hibernate.service: Invalid argument
```

`systemd-analyze verify ...hibernate.service` responds with an empty output.

I copied the unit file straight from the arch wiki and changed SLEEPLENGTH to 1 hour. How can I debug the issue? How can I make systemd issue more descriptive error messages?

**suspend-to-hibernate.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Delayed hibernation trigger
Documentation=https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1420279#p1420279
Documentation=https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management
Conflicts=hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="WAKEALARM=/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
Environment="SLEEPLENGTH=+1hour"
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/sh -c 'echo -n "alarm set for "; date +%%s -d$SLEEPLENGTH | tee $WAKEALARM'
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/sh -c '\
  alarm=$(cat $WAKEALARM); \
  now=$(date +%%s); \
  if [ -z "$alarm" ] || [ "$now" -ge "$alarm" ]; then \
     echo "hibernate triggered"; \
     systemctl hibernate; \
  else \
     echo "normal wakeup"; \
  fi; \
  echo 0 > $WAKEALARM; \
'

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Comment: Where is `suspend-to-hibernate.service`, and have you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after creating/modifying that file?

Comment: `suspend-to-hibernate.service` sits in a sub-folder of my home folder, from where I also run the commands. I was never able to enable it, so I haven't run `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: As given in the Arch wiki page, the file should be in `/etc/systemd/system/`, and you have to `daemon-reload` **before** enabling it (`daemon-reload` gets systemd to recheck its directories for new or modified units, and only after than can you enable a new a service).

Comment: Thanks heaps, this worked. If you sum this up in an answer I'll accept it. I got to say that I find the error message super confusing.... it made me think that there is a syntax error in the file or something like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in the Arch wiki page, the file should be in `/etc/systemd/system/`. There are several directories where systemd looks for unit files, and `/etc/systemd/system/` is where a system administrator should place their service files. See [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

After creating or a modifying a file in these directories, you have to run `systemctl daemon-reload`, which gets systemd to recheck its directories for new or modified units. Only then can you enable or start a new service.